# How do I insert the total continuation count in the allowframbreaks frame title?

Tags: beamer, numbering, frame-title

I would like to change the numbering of `allowframbreaks frame`, for instance, from `I II III` to `(1/3) (2/3) (3/3)`， but fail to find out a command to get the total continuation count. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

%allowframebreaks numbering in the title
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{(\insertcontinuationcount/)}
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{(\insertcontinuationcount/\inserttotalcontinuationcount)}

\title{title}
\author{author}

%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{allowframebreaks title}
frame 1
\framebreak

frame 2
\framebreak

frame 3
\framebreak
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your MWE and make it compilable

Comment: @samcarter thx. I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\inserttotalcontinuationcount` can easily be calculated from the start and end of the frame:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\newcounter{cont}

\makeatletter
%allowframebreaks numbering in the title
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{%
    \setcounter{cont}{\beamer@endpageofframe}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{1}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{-\beamer@startpageofframe}%
    (\insertcontinuationcount/\arabic{cont})%
}
\makeatother

\title{title}
\author{author}

%%%%%
\begin{document}   

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{allowframebreaks title}
    frame 1
    \framebreak

    frame 2
    \framebreak

    frame 3
    \framebreak
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just successfully used your code - works great (this should the default `beamer` behaviour). Can you explain the logic of the three lines containing  `setcounter` and `addcounter`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner These lines calculate the total number of slides within a frame by taking the pagenumber of the last slide of the frame and substracting the pagenumber of the first slide of the frame -> voila, this is the number of slides in the frame.