# How to change how the frame title of a beamer slide presents the frame break number?

Tags: beamer, themes

Using the `allowframebreaks`option on a Beamer frame to split it up with the `\framebreak` command, the title gets an automatic counter.

This is a very handy feature, but I have a few concerns about the default appearance of the counter:

- It gets typeset in roman numbers. With sans serif fonts usually used in presentations, this means the title on the first slide looks very odd.
- It gets appended to the title and typeset as part of the title, while it would often be more appropriate to typeset it as a subscript and/or aligned on right (if the title is aligned on the left)
- I'd prefer the number to appear only from the second frame
- Sometimes it is better to replace the counter with a simpler 
  "(continued)" mark or similar

Are there general options to control this behavior, or is it totally in the hand of how the theme typesets the frame title?

In particular, how can I switch to arabic numbers and make it a subscript? Avoiding the counter on the first slide would also be great.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275044/36296 might be of interest

Comment: Yes, that's what I need!